# Android Emulator won't boot up because of missing files

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I am trying to run my first flutter app on an android emulator. I've installed flutter and Visual Studio Code as well as Android Studio, following the Flutter Getting Started Guide. This worked pretty well except the VM acceleration, but I don't think this causes the error I am encountering. `flutter doctor` returns no errors, and i am able to create a new android emulator in both Android Studio and with flutter. This also workes fine. But when I try to start the emulator, I always encounter the following issue:

```
The Android emulator exited with code -529697949 during startup

Android emulator stderr:
GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\bf22a4e5-2be1-4d17-9893-6baa977f260b: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (2)
GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\b50c5f23-18c7-417f-9238-033242cfcdac: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (2)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: [...] (2x)
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Administrator\.android\avd\..\avd\flutter_emulator.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\bf22a4e5-2be1-4d17-9893-6baa977f260b: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (2)
[...]
Address these issues and try again.
```

I've tried deleting the emulators and recreating them, and also deleted the content from the `emu-crash` folder. The number of missing files increases with every retry.

There are two several issues with the files flutter is looking for:

- The uri has double backslashes between `Temp` and `AndroidEmulator`
- And the `attachments` directory inside `emu-crash` is actually empty

I was able to fix the issue with the `quickbootChoice.ini` file by simply creating one and adding `saveOnExit = true`. But i don't understand why these issues occur with a newly created emulator or how to fix them at all.

I was thinking about reinstalling flutter but I don't know if this would solve the issue. Maybe one of you has encountered this issue or knows a possible solution to this problem?

Thanks alot for your help.

---

Flutter version used:

Flutter is already up to date on channel stable

Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision 41456452f2 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-01-25 10:06:23 -0800

Engine • revision f40e976bed

Tools • Dart 3.2.6 • DevTools 2.28.5

I am using a Windows VM from azure from work, and I am logged in as administrator. Apparently, the nested virtualization has not been enabled, and therefore installing the Android Hypervisor fails. From what I found out, this seems only to be needed for accelerating the emulator, that's why I skipped that part in the flutter guide for now.

Comment: By "Android Hypervisor" you mean Intel Haxm? That software is deprecated anyway.

Comment: I've tried both the "Intel HAXM" and the newer "Android emulator hypervisor driver (Installer)" from the Android Studio SDK Tools. Both fail during the installation, probably because nested virtualization is turned off. Do you think that could be an/the issue?

Comment: The full name of the latter is "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" which indicates it is only for AMD CPUs. At the moment you don't need any of them. Just make sure Hyper-V is enabled in Windows.